# Matching best similar array element

Tags: php, regex, elasticsearch, similarity

I have an array of keywords on which i run `foreach` loop and match each element with specific search term. e.g. i have array like

```
Array(
   [0] => polka dresses
   [1] => polka clothes
   [2] => polka dots dress
   [3] => polka dots bottoms
)
```

and i search for the term `polka` in my array. it gives result when use `strpos` or `stristr` (Also tried `similar_text` but no results).

**Issue**

if i search for `polka` it works but, if accidentally, i type `p0lka` then it do not give any result.
Is there anyway to achieve this.

Comment: `polka`  and `p0lka` are different so it is obvious that you wont get any result, Are you asking about upercase issue. In your question it is Zero '0'

Comment: Perhaps you need to use a suitable string matching algorithm, set threshold of match percentage and select those strings which fall above that threshold.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to get most similar results of a typed word, then you can calculate [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the searched word and stored words and return results which have the least distance.
- You can make use of PHP's [levenshtein](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function for this.

**PHP Snippet:**

```
<?php

$data = array(
   'polka dresses',
   'polka clothes',
   'polka dots dress',
   'polka dots bottoms',
   'dummy dummy'
);

function getSimilarMatches($sentences,$search_str){
    $min_distance = -1;
    $closest_matches = [];

    foreach($sentences as $sentence){
        $min_levenshtein_dist = -1;
        foreach(explode(" ",$sentence) as $word){
            $levenshtein_dist = levenshtein($word,$search_str);
            if($min_levenshtein_dist == -1 ||  $min_levenshtein_dist > $levenshtein_dist){
                $min_levenshtein_dist = $levenshtein_dist;
            }
        }
        if($min_distance == -1 || $min_distance > $min_levenshtein_dist){
            $min_distance = $min_levenshtein_dist;
            $closest_matches = [];
            $closest_matches[] = $sentence;
        }else if($min_distance === $min_levenshtein_dist){
            $closest_matches[] = $sentence;
        }
    }

    return $closest_matches;
}


print_r(getSimilarMatches($data,'polka'));
print_r(getSimilarMatches($data,'p0lka'));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/E9gea

Comment: Many thanks for the script.... it worked.... :) just a lil more help ... can i sort the final result array according to score/relevancy ?

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar I think it's possible. Right now, this code only gives most closest results and ignores everything else. So you get the most relevant only.